# Bootstrap Carousel is not working in asp.net Webform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i have successfully installed bootstrap from nuget Pakage manager all bootstrap elements are working perfectly but carousel is not sliding .
Any help would be appreciated

Here is my Default.aspx Page in which i tried to implement carousel.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>boot test</title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="Images/usman.jpg" alt="..."/>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="Images/usman.jpg" alt="..."/>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
    
    </form>

    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` must come before `bootstrap.min.js`

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it means jquery always need to put before bootstrap.min.js i i should adopt this approach?

Comment: yap, if you check the documentation, that is exactly what it says